# Extract commands used to create docker components

Tags: docker, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an application that for some reason only runs on a Mac and not under WSL. One is using a Kong API router, another is running DB2 LUW in a container, and there are 2 Sprint Boot servers and 2 Angular clients. I can't think of a reason why what we're doing cannot be done on Windows or Linux, but suspect the docker configuration is do blame.

The system behaves as follows. If I enter https://localhost:8443/my-application, it goes directly to my-application. The Kong system should detect that a log in is needed and redirect it to https://company-sso/login and then go to my-application. On MacOS, and apparently only MacOS, it behaves properly.

In fairness, my Docker was originally installed as a Windows application, and I turned on WSL integration.

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                                                                          DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04                                                                                                                                                                                                                      DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal                                                                                                                                                                                                                     DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"                                                                                                                                                                                                   NAME="Ubuntu"                                                                                                                                                                                                                              VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"                                                                                                                                                                                                        ID=ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ID_LIKE=debian                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"                                                                                                                                                                                                           VERSION_ID="20.04"                                                                                                                                                                                                                         HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"                                                                                                                                                                                                         SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"                                                                                                                                                                                                     BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"                                                                                                                                                                                        PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"                                                                                                                                                        VERSION_CODENAME=focal                                                                                                                                                                                                                     UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal          
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
```

Is it possible to go to the Mac, issue some docker command which takes the docker networks, inspects them and gives me a command to re-create it?  Somewhat relatedly, if I go to a database table, right click on it in say DBeaver or similar, it will give me the SQL command to create the table.  I'm hoping to find the same thing for docker objects.

Comment: Networks rarely have interesting setup; if you're manually creating them, just `docker network create NAME` is usually all there is.  For a non-trivial multi-container application you'll usually have some sort of script or Compose setup that starts it and those details will probably be in there.

Comment: @DavidMaze In this case, some of the networks were marked as External. The devops guy takes every new developers machine, does a bunch of secret magic commands and then it works. Some are marked as bridge, others are shared between containers. I suspect the difference lies somewhere in the docker setup.